# No rows returned in DTS task, but returned when debugging script

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dts

I hope I explain this correctly. I have an SSIS Script task which very simply queries a view, fills a datatable with the result and outputs the number of rows that the resultant datatable has.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select .....", conn);
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    output += "Datatable row count " + dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + " \r\n";
                }
```

In Visual Studio this returns the proper result/rowcount (165 rows).  When I save the package and run it as a step in a SQL Server job, it returns a rowcount of 0. (the job runs without errors) Same code, same query, same connection, same credentials only difference is it works when I hit "debug" within the package in Visual Studio but does not when I execute the package as a SQL Server Job step.

Driving me mad! Anyone any ideas? MANY THANKS.

Comment: If you turn on profiler, do you see the connection opened and the same query performed?

Comment: Thanks. In Profiler I see Batch Starting and textdata shows the select query, then BATCH Completed but nothing else (I havent used Profiler much). I output text either side of the datatable row count and it outputs "conn open " and then rowcount then "conn closed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend running via the dtexec command line tool or the dtexecUI to see which behavior it yields. That would help to determine if it's a package issue or job issue. Also, are you running this within a SSIS Script task? If so, SSIS offers a couple of constructs to do this in a more standard (to SSIS) way. For example you could use a OLEDB Source within a DataFlow, then use the RowCount Task for reporting the RowsAffected count that are passed through the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. dtexec from the command line works as expected. The only place the package does not work is as a step within SQL job. I dont know what the difference is?

Comment: How is the job step that executes your package set up? I'm assuming that this is using the step type of "SQL Server Integration Services". A work around would be to use the SQL Job step type of "Operating System (CMDEXE). This could call the dtexec command with the desired parameters to execute your package. To do this though, you'll need to pass in the full path for the dtexec application

Comment: I also meant to mention that I think there may be some permissions issues between the job and the package. So if for some reason you need to run via SQL Server Integration Services job step type, then you may need to delve into the security model to determine more about the package execution.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing in the right direction. When I added a proxy and ran the package using the proxy it worked.